# How to make pause on click for pyautogui script?

Tags: python, queue, pyautogui

I want to make a pause for my script Pyautogui when user make a click and show a dialogbox or reclick for continue at the last paused line.

I try different test but no test successful.

My principal test with Queue when user type "Space" he pause script, but he don't work for a specific command line used.
I want to replace "Space" by "Click".

With this command line is not possible to stop process and continue :

```
a = pyautogui.typewrite('TEST', interval=0.15)
b = pyautogui.typewrite('TEST', interval=0.15)
c = pyautogui.typewrite('TEST', interval=0.15)
d = pyautogui.typewrite('TEST', interval=0.15)
myQueue.enqueue(a)
myQueue.enqueue(b)
myQueue.enqueue(c)
myQueue.enqueue(d)
```

But with this command line is possible to stop process and continue :

```
myQueue.enqueue(1)
myQueue.enqueue(2)
myQueue.enqueue(3)
myQueue.enqueue(4)
myQueue.enqueue(5)
myQueue.enqueue(6)
```

Script :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyautogui
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta

from Tkinter import *

screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position()

yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
three = date.today() - timedelta(3)

d = datetime.datetime.now()
monday = d.isoweekday() in range(1)

class MyLoop():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.running = True
        self.aboutToQuit = False
        self.root = root
        self.someVar = 0
        self.root.bind("<space>", self.switch)
        self.root.bind("<Escape>", self.exit)

        while not self.aboutToQuit:
            self.root.update() # always process new events

            if self.running:
                myQueue = Queue()
                #Insert here specific command line
                a = pyautogui.confirm('TEST')
                b = pyautogui.typewrite('TEST', interval=0.15)
                c = pyautogui.typewrite('TEST', interval=0.15)
                d = pyautogui.typewrite('TEST', interval=0.15)
                e = pyautogui.typewrite('TEST', interval=0.15)
                myQueue.enqueue(a) #prints True
                myQueue.enqueue(b) #prints True
                myQueue.enqueue(c) #prints True
                myQueue.enqueue(d) #prints False
                myQueue.enqueue(e) #prints True
                #Finish to insert
                time.sleep(.1)

            else: # If paused, don't do anything
                time.sleep(.1)

    def switch(self, event):
        print(['Unpausing','Pausing'][self.running])
        self.running = not(self.running)

    def exit(self, event):
        self.aboutToQuit = True
        self.root.destroy()

class Queue:

  #Constructor creates a list
  def __init__(self):
      self.queue = list()

  #Adding elements to queue
  def enqueue(self,data):
      #Checking to avoid duplicate entry (not mandatory)
      if data not in self.queue:
          self.queue.insert(0,data)
          return True
      return False

  #Removing the last element from the queue
  def dequeue(self):
      if len(self.queue)>0:
          return self.queue.pop()
      return ("Queue Empty!")

  #Getting the size of the queue
  def size(self):
      return len(self.queue)

  #printing the elements of the queue
  def printQueue(self):
      return self.queue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw() # don't show the tkinter window
    MyLoop(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The typewrite() function doesn't return anything, it just sends keystrokes to whatever window has focus. Also, PyAutoGUI can't detect when the user clicks the mouse or presses a key, it can only send clicks and keystrokes.

Comment: Big thanks ! I solve the problem with another library pywinauto.